# favicon on safari and ios platforms doesn't appear

Tags: reactjs, iphone, safari, favicon, react-helmet

I am trying to change the favicon dynamically on all browsers, I get a response from the backend containing an https link to the icon, I am using react-helmet to change the favicon but it only works on chrome and android and doesnt work on safari, any ideas? please check out the code below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { FavIconProps } from "./FavIconProps.types";

export const FavIcon = (props: FavIconProps) => {
const { faviconLink } = props;
console.log(faviconLink);
return (
<Helmet>
  <meta name="favicon" />
  <meta data-react-helmet="true" content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
  <meta
    data-react-helmet="true"
    name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"
    content="black-translucent"
  />
  <link id="favicon" rel="icon" data-react-helmet="true" href={faviconLink} />
  <link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    data-react-helmet="true"
    sizes="180x180"
    href={faviconLink} />
</Helmet>
```

);
};

export default FavIcon;